# What exactly do the Market and other buildings increase?

Tags: civilization-4

The effect of Market is given as "+25% coin". Does that mean before or after the division of commerce into science, gold and culture?

In other words, if I have a city bringing in 20 commerce, and the 'sliders' are set at 80% science and 20% gold, does adding a market affect only the gold (adding one gold) or the gold and the science (adding 4 science and one gold)?

Likewise for Bank and the similar buildings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These buildings *only* effect the gold output, and not the science output.  The science percentage-increasing counterparts are buildings such as the Library and University.

In your example, this would translate to +1 gold (and 0 additional science or culture) for building the Market.